# Xhr multiple request javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following script to read the information from an html request.

```
function runSearch(searchid, fullMovie) {    
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var movie = { title: fullMovie.Title, runtime: fullMovie.Runtime, plot: fullMovie.Plot };
        document.getElementById('Title').innerText = movie.title;
        document.getElementById('Runtime').innerText = movie.runtime;
        document.getElementById('Plot').innerText = movie.plot
    }
};
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' +searchid+ '&plot=short&r=json', true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

How can I do to change the searchid from the `xhr.open` to use the `id="searchid"` from a `div` tag?

```
<div>
<div id="tt0110912">
    <h1 id="Title">Title from tt00110912</h1>
    <p id="Runtime">Runtime from id</p>
    <p id="Plot">Plot from id</p>
</div>
</div>
   <br>
<div>
<div id="tt3322364">
   <h1 id="Title">Title from tt3322364</h1>
   <p id="Runtime">Runtime from id</p>
   <p id="Plot">Plot from id`enter code here`</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to run this script several times with different xhr requests? How can i do this if possible?

EDIT: cant make the code work! Theoricaly i need the code to make an xhr request depending on the div id class and fill the information inside that div with the xhr response from that id. Think of a movie database that will show specific movie information from a movie list.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: <div id="runSearch('tt0110912', fullMovie)"> but it isnt working, how can i run the script

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code into function and then call it in loop or manually several times with different `searchid` values.

```
function runSearch(searchid, fullMovie) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var movie = { title: fullMovie.Title, runtime: fullMovie.Runtime, plot: fullMovie.Plot };
            document.getElementById('Title').innerText = movie.title;
            document.getElementById('Runtime').innerText = movie.runtime;
            document.getElementById('Plot').innerText = movie.plot
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + searchid + '&plot=short&r=json', true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
runSearch('your search id', fullMovie);
```

Comment: using <div id="runSearch('tt0110912', fullMovie)"> but it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

> `<div id="runSearch('tt0110912', fullMovie)">`

JavaScript needs to go in a script element (or an intrinsic event attribute, but they are terrible and should be avoided).

The `id` attribute is where you put an identifier for an element. It isn't JavaScript and it makes no sense to put JavaScript there.

```
<script>
runSearch('tt0110912', fullMovie)
</script>
```

---

Your HTML is invalid. An `id` must be unique in a document. You can't reuse the if `Title` (etc) within the same document. Look at using classes instead.

Comment: the id is meant for the script to know what to replace, is there anyway to share my code so you can understand what i need to do? script isnt working, think it is something about the function

Comment: this isnt for me, too hard

Comment: You have to give the containing div a unique id. Pass that id to the function so it knows which set of elements to work on, and use classes within that div for the JS to find to replace the content of.

Comment: i changed the code to original, whats wrong, why the api isnt working?

Comment: how can i do to make javascript read the id and know what to look for?

Comment: @TomasBond — You make the ID one of the arguments you pass to the function (by typing it in when you write the function call)

Comment: i cant understand what should i do, theorical yeas, tell the where to find the fullmovie database, but cant splash it over code